# Javascript Function to split and return a value from a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab a certain value. I am new to javascript and I can't figure out why this is not working.

If I parse "kid_2" I should get "kostas". Instead of "Kostas" I always get "02-23-2000". So I must have a logic problem in the loop but I am really stuck.

```
function getold_val(fieldname,str){

  var chunks=str.split("||");
  var allchunks = chunks.length-1;
     for(k=0;k<allchunks;k++){
       var n=str.indexOf(fieldname);
       alert(chunks[k]);
       if(n>0){
       var chunkd=chunks[k].split("::");
         alert(chunkd);
         return chunkd[1];
       }
     }
}
var test = getold_val('kid_2','date_1::02-23-2000||date_2::06-06-1990||kid_1::George||kid_2::Kostas||');

alert(test);
```

Comment: It should be `allchunks = chunks.length` not `allchunks = chunks.length-1`

Comment: Also, it should be `if(n>=0)` because if the key is found it really is at position 0.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't be returning anything.

Comment: I have tried all of these.. check this it may help you. http://jsbin.com/efajug/3/edit. Problem is that it is stucked in the first split, so the loop is not working right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex may be a little more appealing. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQDXJ/):

```
function getValue(source, key){
    return (new RegExp("(^|\\|)" + key + "::([^$\\|]+)", "i").exec(source) || {})[2];
}    
getValue("date_1::02-23-2000||date_2::06-06-1990||kid_1::George||kid_2::Kostas||","kid_2");
```

But if you want something a little more involved, you can parse that string into a dictionary like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc2pv/)):

```
function splitToDictionary(val, fieldDelimiter, valueDelimiter){
    var dict = {},
    fields = val.split(fieldDelimiter),
    kvp;
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {        
        if (fields[i] !== "") {
            kvp = fields[i].split(valueDelimiter);        
            dict[kvp[0]] = kvp[1];
        }
    }
    return dict;    
}
var dict = splitToDictionary("date_1::02-23-2000||date_2::06-06-1990||kid_1::George||kid_2::Kostas||","||","::");
console.log(dict["date_1"]);
console.log(dict["date_2"]);
console.log(dict["kid_1"]);
console.log(dict["kid_2"]);​
```

Comment: I am a newbie in Jscript so regular expressions  - as you can imagine - was too advanced. I really thank you both suggestions work perfect.

Answer (score 2):

There are two bugs. The first error is in the `indexOf` call:

```
var n = str.indexOf(fieldname);
```

This will always return a value greater than or equal to 0 since the field exists in the string. What you should be doing is:

```
var n = chunks[k].indexOf(fieldname);
```

The second error is in your `if` statement. It should be:

```
if(n >= 0) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if(n > -1) {
    ...
}
```

The substring you are looking for could very well be the at the beginning of the string, in which case its index is 0. `indexOf` returns -1 if it cannot find what you're looking for.

That being said, here's a better way to do what you're trying to do:

```
function getold_val(fieldName, str) {
    var keyValuePairs = str.split("||");
    var returnValue = null;

    if(/||$/.match(str)) {
       keyValuePairs = keyValuePairs.slice(0, keyValuePairs.length - 1);
    }

    var found = false;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < keyValuePairs.length && !found) {
       var keyValuePair = keyValuePairs[i].split("::");

       var key = keyValuePair[0];
       var value = keyValuePair[1];

       if(fieldName === key) {
          returnValue = value;
          found = true;
       }

       i++;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Mihai, good point - my mistake; I didn't see the `||` at the end.

Comment: @VivinPaliath That return looks correct though. It is only executed if the key matches.

Comment: I really think the real bug is the `if` statement.

Comment: Don't use indexOf. Do `chunks[k].split('::')[0] = fieldname`. Think what will happen with `kid_10`

Comment: If `kid10` is passed in, wouldn't that just give a -1?

Comment: No, think about if `kid_10` exists and `kid_1` is passed in.

Comment: Alternatively you can also do `indexOf(fieldname+"::")`

Comment: Yeap you are right. The main problem was the var n = chunks[k].indexOf(fieldname); Thank you very very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This works, here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cBYy/).

```
function getold_val(fieldname,str) {
    var chunks = str.split('||');
    for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length-1; i++) {
        if(chunks[i].indexOf(fieldname) >= 0) {
            return(chunks[i].substring(fieldname.length+2));
        }
    }
}
alert(getold_val('kid_2', 'date_1::02-23-2000||date_2::06-06-1990||kid_1::George||kid_2::Kostas||'));
```

The issue with your code was (as @slebetman noticed as well) the fact that a string index can be 0 because it starts exactly in the first letter.

The code is almost the same as yours, I just didn't use the second `.split('::')` because I felt a `.substring(...)` would be easier.

Comment: my god you're very fast. Let me check it one moment please.

Comment: Actually, the main problem was that he was doing `str.indexOf()` instead of `chunks[i].indexOf()`. So while looking at the first chunk, it would find the fieldname in a different chunk.

Comment: Actually, using indexOf is also a bug. Should simply split everything into an array of arrays (or array of objects) and simply check if `key = fieldname`. This will break on `kid_10` and above.

Comment: your code works great but I had to add "+2" to get ride of the dots. return(chunks[i].substring(fieldname.length+2)); I'll keep searching how to do it with the "::" as a seperator. @Barman I think you saw exactly the problem. I'll test it in a minute.

Comment: I figured it out by adding lots of `console.log` statements. When I logged n it said it was something like 65!

Comment: @GeorgeD. There's still a bug here. If the `str` contains `kid_10` but not `kid_1` and you try to search for `kid_1` you will get a single colon plus the kid's name

Comment: You are right Slebetman. :-) I did some tests and when I put more than 10 I got a mess.